# Efficient loading of images and videos first frame in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, video-streaming, rx-java

Working on media browser type of application where I read files from USB  with custom drivers. File expose by `NanoHTTPServer`. Not important point here but just for information.

The following code logic works pretty well but it looks broken and start struggling with fast scrolling.
Is there any way to load videos frame faster and avoid hanging and delay in frames. Is there any flaws in this code? As I am using rxjava.

```
    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(BasicHolder holder,final int position) {
    ...
    if(multiMedia.isImage()){
    Glide.with(context)
                        .load(multiMedia.getUrl())
                        .crossFade()
                        .into(holder.imageThumbnail);
    }else{
    Bitmap bitmap = mThumbnailsCache.get(multiMedia.getUrl()+THUMBNAIL_AT_PERCENT);
                if(bitmap == null || multiMedia.getLength() == 0){
                    //check for already running task
                    if(holder.imageThumbnail.getTag(R.string.tag_for_video) == null){
                        loadVideoThumbnail(holder,multiMedia,position);
                    }
                }else {
                    holder.imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
    }
    ....
//this method will trigger rxjava task on io and set back results emitted by
    private void loadVideoThumbnail(final BasicHolder holder, final MultiMedia multiMedia,final int position){
            final SoftReference<BasicHolder> mHolderRef = new SoftReference<>(holder);
            final Subscription sub = extractFrameAndDuration(multiMedia.getUrl(), THUMBNAIL_AT_PERCENT)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(emittedObject -> {
                        if (emittedObject == null || mHolderRef.get() == null) return;

                        if (mHolderRef.get().getLayoutPosition() != position) {
                            notifyItemChanged(position);
                            return;
                        }

                        if (emittedObject instanceof Bitmap) {
                            ImageView imageThumbnail = mHolderRef.get().imageThumbnail;
                            if (imageThumbnail.getTag(R.string.tag_for_video) != null) {
                                imageThumbnail.setTag(R.string.tag_for_video, null);
                                imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) emittedObject);
                            }
                        } else {
                            multiMedia.setLength((long)emittedObject);
                            TextView textInfo = mHolderRef.get().textInfo;
                            if (textInfo.getTag() == Filetype.MOVIE) {
                                mHolderRef.get().viewHighlight.setData(multiMedia.getSavedClips(),multiMedia.getLength());
                                textInfo.setText(VideoUtils.getTotalClipDuration((long) emittedObject, App.context));
                            }
                        }
                    }, Throwable::printStackTrace);

            if(reqSubQueue.size() > 8){
                //cancel previous requests
                reqSubQueue.pop().unsubscribe();
            }
            reqSubQueue.add(sub);
            holder.imageThumbnail.setTag(R.string.tag_for_video,sub);
        }

    ...
    //this method will get thumbnail from video url
    private Observable<Object> extractFrameAndDuration(String url, final long atPercent){
            return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
                final MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                subscriber.add(new Subscription() {
                    @Override
                    public void unsubscribe() {
                       //this will actually cancel loading
                        Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
                            mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
                            return true;
                        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .subscribe();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean isUnsubscribed() {
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                try{
                    mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(url, new HashMap<>());

                    String durationString = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
                    final long duration = Long.parseLong(TextUtils.isEmpty(durationString)? "0": durationString);

                    //cache duration
                    clipsDurations.put(url,duration);

                    subscriber.onNext(duration);

                    long timeUs = (long) (duration / 100.0 * atPercent);

                    if(timeUs > duration) timeUs = duration;

                    Bitmap bitmap = mThumbnailsCache.get(url+THUMBNAIL_AT_PERCENT);
                    if(bitmap == null){
                        //1 milli sec = 1000 microseconds
                        bitmap = MediaUtils.getFrameFromVideoAt(mediaMetadataRetriever, timeUs * 1000);
                        if(bitmap != null){
                            bitmap = MediaUtils.resize(bitmap,thumbSize,thumbSize);
                            mThumbnailsCache.put(url+THUMBNAIL_AT_PERCENT,bitmap);
                            subscriber.onNext(bitmap);
                        }
                    }else {
                        subscriber.onNext(bitmap);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    if (mediaMetadataRetriever != null){
                        mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
                    }
                }
                //remove item from queue
                subscriber.onCompleted();
                reqSubQueue.remove(subscriber);
            });
        }
```

All requests get canceled in `Activity.onStop`. `reqSubQueue` is `ArrayDeque`

*Edit* method description is added

I am sure some pro-developers will find out flaws.

Comment: please give some brief about your code, maybe some general explanation regarding each method

Comment: @yosriz check out comments above methods. Thanks